# Groupification and perfection of a commutative monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

The following definitions and proposition are taken from the paper [The geometry of Frobenioids I](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~motizuki/papers-english.html) by S. Mochizuki.

Let $\mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}$ be the set of positive integers.
$\mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}$ is a directed set by the order relation $a|b$.
Let $M$, $N$ be commutative monoids(the binary operations are written additively).
A map $f\colon M \rightarrow N$ is called a morphism if $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ for any $x, y$ and $f(0) = 0$.

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}$, the multiplication map $x \rightarrow nx$ on $M$ is a morphism.

$M$ is said to be *torsion-free* if $nx = 0$ implies $x = 0$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}$.

Let $M^{gp}$ be the *groupification* of $M$, i.e. [the grothendieck group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_group) of $M$.
Let $\psi\colon M \rightarrow M^{gp}$ be the canonical map.
If $\psi$ is injective, $M$ is said to be *integral*.

$M$ is said to be *saturated* if $na \in \psi(M)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}$ and $a \in M^{gp}$, then $a \in \psi(M)$.

$M$ is said to be *perfect* if the multiplication map $x \rightarrow nx$ is bijective for every $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}$.

The *perfection* $M^{pf}$ of $M$ is defined as follows.
Let $M_a = M$ for every $a \in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}$.
if $a|b$, we define a morphism $f_{ba}\colon M_a \rightarrow M_b$ by $f_{ba}(x) = (b/a)x$.
Then $(M_a)_{a\in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}}$ and $(f_{ba})$ consitute a direct(or inductive) system.
We define $M^{pf} = colim_{a\in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}} M_a$.
There exists the canonical morphism $\phi\colon M = M_1 \rightarrow M^{pf}$.

**My question:**
How do we prove the following proposition?

**Proposition**

(1) $\phi\colon M \rightarrow M^{pf}$ is injective if $M$ is torsion-free, integral, and saturated.

(2) $M$ is perfect if and only if $\phi$ is an isomorhism.

**Motivation**
Recently(August, 2012), S. Mochizuki submitted a series of papers([Inter-universal Teichmuller Theory I,II,III,IV](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~motizuki/papers-english.html)) which develops his new theory. As an application of his theory, he wrote a proof of ABC conjecture.
I think the validity of the proof has not yet been confirmed by other mathematicians.
However, considering his track record, I think it's worthwhile to read the papers.
He referred to [The geometry of Frobenioids I](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~motizuki/papers-english.html) for the notation and terminolgy concerning monoids and categories.

Comment: @user18921 I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. Could you rephrase it?

Answer (score 1):

(1) If $M \to M^{pf}$ is not injective,  there exist $x \neq y$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ such that $f_{n1}(x) = f_{n1}(y)$. (The fact that elements are equal in the colimit iff they are equal in some term requires some thought. It is not a general property; it follows here from the structure of the diagram defining the colimit.) So let us assume that $x,y\in M$ satisfy $nx = ny$.

Let $Z = [x] - [y]$ in $M^{gp}$. We have $nZ = [nx] - [ny] = 0$, which lies in the image $\psi(M)$, so saturation implies that $Z \in \psi(M)$. Say $Z=\psi(z)$ for $z\in M$. Since $Z$ satisfies $Z + [y] = [x]$, integrality implies that $z + y = x$. The element $z$ satisfies $\psi(nz)=nZ=0\in M^{gp}$, so integrality implies $nz = 0\in M$. Since $M$ is torsion-free this implies $z = 0$, so $z+y=x$ becomes $y = x$. This shows that $M\to M^{pf}$ is injective.

(2) Since $M^{pf}$ is perfect (an inverse to $x\mapsto nx$ is the map induced by sending $x\in M_a$ to $x\in M_{na}$), an isomorphism $M\to M^{pf}$ implies that $M$ is perfect. Conversely, if $M$ is perfect, we can change coordinates on $M_a$ by $x \mapsto \frac{1}{n}x$ (the inverse of $x\mapsto nx$, which is automatically a morphism). Now the direct system is constant and so $M\to M_1\to M^{pf}$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I think (1) is correct.
However I don't understand (2) fully.
Could you elaborate on it?

Comment: If $M$ is perfect, then each map $f_{ba}\colon M_a\to M_b$ is an isomorphism of monoids. Therefore the colimit is boring: it is isomorphic to $M_1$. (To see this, check that for any $a\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ and any $x\in M_a$, there exists some $y\in M_1$ so that $f_{a1}(y)=x$. This is worth working out.)

Answer (score 0):

Aha. What does this '$\mathrm{colim}$' means? $M^{pf} = \displaystyle(\coprod_{a\in\mathbb N} M_a)/\sim$, where $m_a$ and $m_b$ are *identified* ($m_a\sim m_b$), if $a|b$ and $m_b = (b/a)\cdot m_a$.

Somehow, $M_a$ wants to represent the 'formal' $a$-fractions of $M$, regarding that any $m$ in $M_1$ is represented as $a\cdot m$ in $M_a$, so $m$ in $M_a$ wants to represent $\frac 1a\cdot m$.

Now pick $m,u$ such that $\phi(m)=\phi(u)$, denote $m_1$ and $u_1$ the (copy of) $m$ and $u$ in $M_1$, so it means $m_1=u_1$. 
Identity in $M^{pf}$ means that
$$\exists m_1\sim w_{a_1} \sim w_{a_2} \sim \dots \sim w_{a_k} \sim u_1 $$
i.e., $w_{a_1}=a_1\cdot m_1$,  next one is either $w_{a_2}=(a_2/a_1)\cdot w_{a_1} = a_2\cdot m_1$, or $w_{a_1} = (a_1/a_2)w_{a_2}$
...

Comment: I got stucked, too.. sorry,
Turn back on that later.