# Monoid with torsion elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

I am currently studying construction of the Grothendieck group of a commutative monoid $M$. I was looking for an example of a monoid that is torsion, namely, I have the following query.

Does there exist a monoid $M$ (written multiicatively with identity element denoted by $1$) that is not a group such that $x \in M$ implies $x^n = 1$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: If for every $x\in M$ there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (which I assume to you means *positive* integers) such that $x^n=1$, then $x^{n-1}$ is an inverse of $x$; so for every $x$, $x$ has an inverse; so you  have a monoid in which every element is invertible. That's called a group.

Comment: But that's not a good definition of "torsion" (see e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/216623/742)). I would say an element $x$ of a monoid is "torsion" if and only if there exist $n\neq m$ such that $x^n=x^m$.

Comment: Yes I understand your point, Thank you very much!